# how to make a blurry lazy image loading for your website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, zend-framework

I have a website full with images and the web site performance is so bad.

I want to make the images load blurry then on scroll event the images will bi loaded.

I'm using PHP and Zend framework

I'm searching for a java script library or php function that help me make an lazy load image but I wasn't able to find one that can be easy to use because I don't want to replace all the images manulay

I tried progressive-image.js the performance enhanced a little bit , my main goal is to make the minimum number of requests

is there any script that work the same as google images

i'v seen that code snippet

```
 function imageLoaded(e) {
   updateImage(e.target, 'loaded');
 }

function imageError(e) {
  updateImage(e.target, 'error');
}

function updateImage(img, classname) {
  // Add the right class:
  img.classList.add(classname);

  // Remove the data-src attribute:
  img.removeAttribute('data-src');

  // Remove both listeners:
  img.removeEventListener('load', imageLoaded);
  img.removeEventListener('error', imageError);
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(img => {
    const src = img.getAttribute('data-src');

    if (src) {
      // Listen for both events:
      img.addEventListener('load', imageLoaded);
      img.addEventListener('error', imageError);

      // Just to simulate a slow network:
      setTimeout(() => {
        img.setAttribute('src', src);
      }, 2000 + Math.random() * 2000);
    }
  });
})
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.margin-fix {
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 16px;
}

img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 64px;
  background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,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");
}

img.loaded {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img.error {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;

  /* You could add a custom "error" image here using background-image */
}
```

```
  <img
    src
    data-src="https://d39a3h63xew422.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/20145029/driven-by-design-the-incomparable-lancia-stratos-1476934711918-1000x573.jpg" />

  <img
    src
    data-src="https://car-images.bauersecure.com/pagefiles/76591/1752x1168/ford_racing_puma_01.jpg?mode=max&quality=90&scale=down" />

  <img
    src
    data-src="http://doesntexist.com/image.jpg" />

  <span class="margin-fix"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: _“and I want to view a blurred image instead of the spinner how to make that happen”_ - by replacing the spinner GIF that currently gets applied as background image to all those images, with a specific blurred image for each one individually. Of course you will have to _create_ those blurred miniature versions out of all your full-size images first …

Comment: _“because I don't want to replace all the images manulay”_ - then you will probably have to do that using a script on the server side instead. If you send `<img src="...">` to the browser directly, it _will_ start loading that image, as soon as it encounters the element.

Comment: Maybe you want to use Progressive Jpeg-s? https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/what-is-a-progressive-jpeg/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nowdays it's more common that javascript is the dead weight. spending time decompressing, parsing and compiling - a larger image may sometimes be faster.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/javascript-startup-optimization/

There is alternativ ways also like using `loading="lazy"` to only load stuff that is in the viewport. no javascript needed! also more SEO friendly.

```
<img src="image.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="..." />
<iframe src="video-player.html" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

also take some look at the request header and look at what they are requesting.

- Browsers are sending `accept-type` with a bunch of formats. WebP may reduce the size more than jpg and still look good with lossy compression.
- They may also send `Save-Data` request header to prefer reduced size over speed, perhaps serve them a smaller image that you then upscale.
- some even send [client-hints](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/leaner-responsive-images-client-hints/) like Accept-CH: DPR, Width, Viewport-Width

---

frankly i have disabled javascript in my mobile brave browser cuz so much junk shows ups all the time. cookie notif, ads, subscriptions, permission request, so i prefer if you just used `loading="lazy"`

you could also take a look at srcset for responsive images https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: Is it possible to add a css animation (blur for example) with this implimentation?